# Wrapping component breaks style

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

```
const Login = () => (
  <FlatButton label="Login" />
);

export class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <MuiThemeProvider>
          <AppBar
            iconElementRight={<Login />}
          />
        </MuiThemeProvider>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The results is a button with broken styling.

Here is an image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/d9oAs.png

However, inserting the component directly works perfectly fine.
Like this:

```
      <AppBar
        iconElementRight={<FlatButton label="Login" />}
      />
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4AZsp.png

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

Comment: whats your css like that is styling the button? does it use any descendant or child selectors?

Comment: I have no CSS apart from what is included by Material UI

Comment: can you have a browser window open with the one result and then another browser window open with the alternate result and then use the DOM inspector to see whats different between the two elements?

Comment: The problem seems to be that the first solution wraps the component in an extra div, so when it tries to inherit styling it doesnt work. Any idea of how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

material-ui's AppBar.js specifically looks at what type of component you put in `iconElementRight`, and then applies an appropriate style on it if its a native material-ui `IconMenu`, `IconButton`, or `FlatButton`.  If you wrap any of those, the detection fails, and the style won't be applied.  So, you'll have to apply that same style yourself to your `<Login />` component (looks like its just `color`, and a calculated `marginTop`).

Relevant code from AppBar.js...

https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/master/src/AppBar/AppBar.js

```
const flatButtonSize = 36;

const styles = {
  // ...
  flatButton: {
    color: appBar.textColor,
    marginTop: (iconButtonSize - flatButtonSize) / 2 + 1,
  },
  // ...
};

// ...

switch (iconElementRight.type.muiName) {
  case 'IconMenu':
  case 'IconButton':
    // ...
    break;
  case 'FlatButton':
    iconElementRightProps.style = Object.assign({}, styles.flatButton, iconElementRight.props.style);
    break;
  default:
}
```

Example:

```
// Using material-ui's default IconButton size of 48... (48 - 36) / 2 + 1 = 7
<Login style={{ color: 'white', marginTop: 7 }} />
```

Comment: An alternative - which feels hacky, so not sure I recommend - would be to juat add the line "Login.muiName = 'FlatButton';" after your class declaration. That would fool MUI into treating your Login as if it were a native FlatButton and apply the style for you.

Answer (score 0):

You may already know this but just in case, if you wrap `<MuiThemeProvider></MuiThemeProvider>`around the parent JSX file, you will only have to call it there instead of in every file. It could be that the multiple instances of MuiThemeProvider are causing the issue.[image: Note that the left file is the parent managing the theme and the <AppBar /> component still inherits the style]